# RecyclerView not displaying elements from list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I've tried creating a RecyclerView which displays the songs I have on my phone from a pre-populated ArrayList. Here is my code for my activity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private RecyclerView songRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter songRecyclerAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerLayoutManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    //get the songs list for the adapter
    ArrayList<Audio> songList;
    StorageUtils storageUtils = new StorageUtils(getApplicationContext());
    songList = storageUtils.loadAudio();


    //Recycler view setup for songs display
    songRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    songRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    songRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerLayoutManager);


    songRecyclerAdapter = new SongAdapter(songList);
    songRecyclerView.setAdapter(songRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

The Audio class has the getTitle() and getArtist() methods, which do work. The loud audio() also works so Songlist definitely has elements in it. 
Here is the xml of the recyclerview item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:visibility="visible">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_item_songName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="song name"
    android:textColor="@color/textPrimary"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_item_artistName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="song artist"
    android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler_item_songName" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my implementation of the Adapter:

```
package com.ecebuc.gesmediaplayer;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SongAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    // The dataset
    private ArrayList<Audio> songList;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView recyclerTitleView, recyclerArtistView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.recyclerTitleView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_item_songName);
            this.recyclerArtistView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_item_artistName);
        }
    }

    // Constructor
    public SongAdapter(ArrayList<Audio> songList){
        this.songList = songList;
    }

    @Override
    public SongAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View listItemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.song_list_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItemView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Audio currentSong = songList.get(position);
        holder.recyclerTitleView.setText(currentSong.getTitle());
        holder.recyclerArtistView.setText(currentSong.getArtist());
        Log.d("onBind: ", (String)holder.recyclerTitleView.getText() + (String)holder.recyclerArtistView.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songList.size();
    }

}
```

The frustrating thing is that at my very first attempt at creating the whole recycleView, it did work and displayed the text. I tried adding an imageView as the cover of the songs to the layout of each item in the list, and the code to display that as well, and it wasn't working anymore. When tried to revert and have only the code for text, it stopped working altogether.

I am bashing my head over this because if I did make some small change somewhere, I don't know where it might be any more now. But I did try to recreate the class for the adapter and the layout file for the whole recycler functionality from scratch, and still not showing. The layout items have to be there because I see the shadow of the scroll.

Also, in the adapter's onBindViewHolder, that Log.d displays correctly each song title and artist. And it calls the newly created views' getText(). It's like the text was white. And no, the values of @color/text primary and textSecondary in the XML are #212121 and #424242 and were always like that (again, it did display the values the first time, and I haven't touched the colours).

I've looked for similar problems on StackOverflow and online, but I don't seem to have that kind of mistakes. I don't know what to do anymore. Heck, I'll even include the XML of the screen that has the actual recyclerView in it. At this point I don't know what could make those views invisible:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Finally, I thought of looking at the developer options on my phone and display layout outlines, and this is what I had...as if the two textViews are not being created, yet I was able to get their text content after I've set it, so how is that even possible? Thank you to whoever can help me, I'm just trying to learn here... [image: Layout outlines]

Comment: Woah!! Trust me your code looks perfect and my initial reaction was like you made the text white. OK! I have something for you to test. Just try adding hardcode values in xml of the recyclerview item. Like 1st textview text = "abc" and 2nd "test". See if it populates and comment out the lines in the onBindView

Comment: looks like still nothing...
There were already some hardcoded values in the xml of the item that I put there from the beginning just for the sake of initialization. But yeah, still empty lines @Pulkit

Comment: In xml of the recyclerview item instead of contraint layout try linear layout or something else just to test it out. I think maybe the items in the xml are outside the view to be displayed.

Comment: okay...interesting. With LinearLayout the hardcoded values appear to be working, I'll try now to see if the ones from my dataset are loaded correctly too.

Comment: Yup, working with everything I give it, hardcoded, strings passed at runtime, and my values too. The only thing now is...I'd kinda need that constraint layout though, in the sense that it would suit well my needs, also for the future features like having the song cover image, and other textViews in it. What of it could have been the problem that made the layout break? @Pulkit

Comment: Wait so it worked without constraint layout?

Comment: Or the better question would be, how could I as the programmer see if those items in the xml were outside the view to be displayed? I could see them well placed within it, set constraints and everything

Comment: Yes, changing the constraint layout to linear layout, and leaving everything else exactly the same in the layout worked @Pulkit

Comment: Just my wild guess maybe your data in the views are being filled but the textviews constraints were not right, like maybe the constraints set by you maybe forcing the textviews to display it outside the normal view window of the phone. Try rotating the screen in constraint layout and see if the views are still there or maybe open the app on Tablet also.

Comment: @Pulkit
Nah, don't think that was the problem, because I just changed again to constraint layout...works perfectly. Haven't modified a thing in the whole layout. Just from constraint layout to linear, and then back to constraint... Why? Two good hours lost just like that...
Thank you very much for the help and suggestions though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference in case anyone has a similar problem, I managed to solve it by simply changing my constraint layout in the recycler view item XML, to linear layout (or I'd guess whatever type of layout other than constraint) and compiled.

It worked well, displaying everything correctly. Then changing the XML back to constraint layout like before, and everything was still working fine. At this point I'd say it will forever remain a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

make some change in adapter constructor like below code..

```
    public Context context;
// Constructor
public SongAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Audio> songList){
    this.context=context;
    this.songList = songList;
}
```

then after main activity make adapter object like below ..

```
SongAdapter adapter;
```

and remove this line of code ..

```
private RecyclerView.Adapter songRecyclerAdapter;
```

and used set adapter like below code..

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
SongAdapter songRecyclerAdapter;
private void setAdapter(){
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    if (songRecyclerAdapter==null) {
        songRecyclerAdapter = new SongAdapter(this,songList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(songRecyclerAdapter);
        songRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } 
    else{
        songRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```